# What does the name "Evergarden" in Violet Evergarden mean exactly?

Tags: violet-evergarden

I found the meaning of the word "Evergarden" from [here](https://www.names.org/n/evergarden/about):

> A user from Mauritius says the name Evergarden is of French origin and means "Love of humanity".

But I am not sure if we can rely on this. I also saw Evergarden used in other context, but I am wondering if there's a particular meaning for her last name.

I know throughout the show, flowers are used as symbolism, so I am wondering if her last name also has a meaning similar to violet, which does have some symbolic meaning in the show.

**Question**: What is the meaning of the word "Evergarden" from the context of the anime *Violet Evergarden*?

Comment: See this reddit post (Warning spoilers): https://www.reddit.com/r/VioletEvergarden/comments/8343ee/spoiler_i_guess_why_evergarden/

Comment: Not a full answer but what I believe is that when Tiffany Evergarden (head of the prestigious Evergarden family) adopted Violet, she might have gave her the family name out of genuine love and considered her to be foster daughter. From wiki:  "She feels vexed about the fact that they have no blood relation and that she cannot replace Gilbert. Despite that, Tiffany still genuinely cares for and loves Violet. She claims that she would never abandon her cute daughter with sincere innocence (as she describes Violet as) and would rather rather sell off her husband".

Comment: Seconding @FumikageTokoyami 's comment, there might be a *reason* why she got that name, but there might *not* be a (deeper/literal) *meaning* of it.